# Is Hazelcast's split brain recovery merge operation transactional?

Tags: hazelcast

Just starting to learn about Hazelcast so apologies for any ignorance below...

Hazelcast conducts a "merge" operation after recovery from a split-brain scenario. This is described [here](http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/networkpartitioning.html).

I'm trying to determine if this merge operation appears as an atomic operation, from both the point of view of the merging cluster and the point of view of the cluster being merged into. This is assuming a map that is set up for two-phase commit.

It appears [from the description](http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/networkpartitioning.html) that it is indeed transactional for the merging cluster (it says "pause" ... then "resume").

Less clear is the situation on the cluster being merged into. Are all the merged values applied in a single transaction, or is each merged value merged in a separate transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs it looks like the machines from the merging cluster are not gurateed to perform the merge "all together". I understand the process as like each node merges into the bigger cluster separately. So my guess is that there are multiple transactions.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected.